# PHP get raw data of PDF to POST using CURL

Tags: php, pdf, curl, fopen, fread

I have been tryign to get the raw contents of a PDF file using PHP to `POST` to an API using `CURL`.  I have tried using `file_get_contents` (though the resulting file is not readable) and I have tried

```
$filename = "/files/example.pdf";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

Then I post contents and again the file is not readable by a PDF reader

Any idea's?

Thanks

Comment: You're reading the file just fine. The problem is probably in your `POST` code.

Comment: Or your file path could be wrong.

Comment: If I echo it out directly into the brower and add header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); it works just fine. - Will check with the guys that own the API.  Thanks